# Apache, Tomcat : Loadbalancing and failover configuration showing blank page.

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, load-balancing, failover

I am working on adding load-balancing and fail-over functionality to our existing Apache tomcat setup with mod_jk. For this, I have setup 2 Tomcat instances. I have made some changes, and will be pasting them. I am not getting any errors in the log of either httpd or tomcat, and I am only seeing a blank page. What am I doing wrong?

Apache webserver config :

workers.properties :

```
worker.list=loadbalancer
 worker.server1.port=8010
 worker.server1.host=localhost
 worker.server1.lbfactor=1
 worker.server1.type=ajp13


 worker.server2.port=8011
 worker.server2.host=localhost
 worker.server2.type=ajp13
 worker.server2.lbfactor=1


 worker.loadbalancer.type=lb
 worker.loadbalancer.balance_workers=server1,server2

worker.loadbalancer.sticky_session=true
worker.myworker.sticky_session_force=True
```

apache2.conf / httpd.conf :

```
Include sites-enabled/

LoadModule jk_module modules/mod_jk.so
JkWorkersFile /etc/apache2/workers.properties
JkLogFile   /etc/apache2/mod_jk.log
JkMount /* loadbalancer
```

sites-enabled/000-default : Only contains :

```
 JkMountCopy On
```

First tomcat's server.xml :

```
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">

 <Connector port="8081" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" connectionTimeout="20000"/>

  <Connector port="8010" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8081" URIEncoding="utf-8"
 compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml,text/plain,text/css,text/ javascript,application/x-javascript,application/javascript"
/>
<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="server1">
         <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster">
</Cluster>
    </Engine>
```

2nd Tomcat's server.xml :

```
<Server port="8006" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">

 <Connector port="8080" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" connectionTimeout="20000"/>
 <Connector port="8011" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8080" URIEncoding="utf-8"
 compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml,text/plain,text/css,text/ javascript,application/x-javascript,application/javascript"
/>
  <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="server2">
     <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster">
  </Cluster>
        </Engine>
```

Even if I shut down any tomcat, all I see is a blank page. What am I doing wrong? Kindly let me know. Thanks a lot.. :-)

Comment: Any messages in your httpd log file? Or in `mod_jk.log`? Note that if you are using sticky sessions, setting up a cluster isn't really necessary unless you absolutely need failover.

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz : The problem was in sites-enabled/000-default. When I changed JkMountCopy on to JkMount /* loadbalancer, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

It's not usually worth it to specify any `JkMount` directives outside of a `VirtualHost`. You should be specific and map them to each VH.

`JkMountCopy` should have worked for you. I suspect that some other configuration was interfering with it.

Comment: Yes, I had to put it inside VH as we had SSL, so I created a VH with _default_:443 and inside that I put these. Although when I restart apache I keep getting warning, no hosts for port 80 defined. Our entire webapp runs on https, like /**.

Comment: If you get warnings about "no hosts for port 80," maybe you should stop having `httpd` listen on port 80.

Comment: Where am I listening to port-80, I checked ssl.conf and apache2.conf. Also nothing in sites-enabled/000-default.

Comment: The line you are looking for is `Listen 80` and might be buried in another file. Just use `grep` to search all the files in the `/etc/httpd` or `/etc/apache2` subtrees.